# (OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using Facebook C# sdk with the code,

i'm trying to create a new score for a user

but i get this error:

**(OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.**

what am i missing?

```
protected void btnAddScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CanvasAuthorizer.Authorize())
    {
        var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.score = 77;
        parameters.access_token = GetAppAccessToken();
        try
        {
            dynamic id = fb.Post("me/scores", parameters);
            lblPostMessageResult.Text = "Message posted successfully";
            txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException ex)
        {
            lblPostMessageResult.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
private string GetAppAccessToken()
{
    var oauthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient
    {
        AppId = FacebookWebContext.Current.Settings.AppId,
        AppSecret = FacebookWebContext.Current.Settings.AppSecret
    };

    dynamic result = oauthClient.GetApplicationAccessToken();
    string appAccessToken = result.access_token;
    return appAccessToken;
}
```

---

edit:
I got the answer form here:
http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/279307

the new right code is:

```
if (CanvasAuthorizer.Authorize())
{
    var fb = new FacebookClient(CanvasAuthorizer.FacebookWebRequest.AccessToken);

    var oauthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient(FacebookApplication.Current);

    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.score = 100;
    dynamic ac = oauthClient.GetApplicationAccessToken();
    parameters.access_token = ac.access_token;
    dynamic result = fb.Post(CanvasAuthorizer.FacebookWebRequest.UserId + "/scores", parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:-**

Actually for using SCORE Graph API you need the "Application access token" which is different than a normal access token

So if you want your task to be done GET an Application access token by using the following script.......

And then replace the generated application_access_token with old access_token, that's it

The below code is written in php try convert it in c# and then apply it

```
$APPLICATION_ID = "APP_ID";
$APPLICATION_SECRET = "APP_SECRET";

$token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
                "client_id=" . $APPLICATION_ID .
                "&client_secret=" . $APPLICATION_SECRET .
                "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
```

After getting this application access token you can easily do this task.

**When You Need An Application Access Token**

You need to use a Facebook application access token when you have a process that acts on behalf of the application, rather than on behalf of a particular user. This happens when you access your Facebook Insights data for your app via the graph, and also when you want to create test Facebook users for your app.

Sadly, the documentation for this is buried in the [authentication guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) for the Facebook graph API.

Answer (score 0):

Your application need to take "publish_actions" permission from user to update the score.

Refer to **Create or update a score for a user** section of the below documentation.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/